# Use Powershell to add items to Access Protection in McAfee Enterprise

Tags: email, powershell, mcafee

I'm guessing this won't work for security reasons, but I thought I'd ask anyway.  I'm trying to use powershell to send email notifications for maintenance. I've got the actual notifications and everything working, I just have to add an exception on the access protection -> Anti-Virus Standard Protection -> Prevent mass mailing worms. My problem is that it seems ePO pushes the policy every couple of minutes and disables this.  Is there any other way to temporarily add this exception so I can schedule these emails? Is this in the registry somewhere? The ePO admins aren't responsive to my request to exclude me from that policy. Like I said, it probably isn't possible for security reasons but I was hoping maybe someone had an idea on how to do this or maybe another idea of how I should do this.

My script pulls the name from an excel sheet, looks up the email in the global address book, and then sends it from an alias. It uses system.net.mail.smtpClient to send the message.  I could use the outlook com object, but I want to be able to send from an alias instead of my personal email address. I can change the replyrecipients, but that only changes the replyto address and not the from address. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this isn't possible.  I wound up having to use the outlook object to send out the emails which circumvents the McAfee access protection issue I was running into.